# coding multiple variables that have NA's

Tags: r

I created variables in R and for some individuals, the person's value is appearing as NA.

```
id   x_SD   y_SD
1    NA      5
2    34      9
3    5       NA
```

For all variables that have an ending of "_SD", I want the `NA` values to be 0. Like so:

```
id   x_SD   y_SD
1    0       5
2    34      9
3    5       0
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(ends_with('_SD'), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
#We can also use `replace_na` from tidyr
#df %>% mutate(across(ends_with('_SD'), tidyr::replace_na, 0))

#  id x_SD y_SD
#1  1    0    5
#2  2   34    9
#3  3    5    0
```

---

In base R  you can select the columns that you want to change to 0 and replace them directly.

```
cols <- grep('_SD$', names(df))
df[cols][is.na(df[cols])] <- 0
```

Comment: I see that instead of it being blanks, that they are appearing as missing (NA). I tried this: GEST_final_1[cols][GEST_final_1[cols] == NA] <- 0 --but it did not work. Do you know how I can change the code to get this to work?

Comment: I apologize, Ronak. I didn't realize. Thank you for your help--that ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with('_SD'),  ~na_if(., 0)))
```